# audio.duration property not reseting when stop function is executed

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

when 'stop' is pressed the audio.duration doesn't reset to ("00:00"). I've tried various methods...
Commented out in the function code.

```
function stop() {

audio.pause();
audio.currentTime = 0;
//audio.duration =  0;                                                                                                
//document.getElementById("duration-time").innerHTML = "00:00";
//document.getElementById("duration-time").textContent = "00:00";
//durtimetext.textContent = "00:00";
//durtimetext.innerHTML = "00:00";

}
```

The other two lines work, but just can't get Audio-duration span to reset to "00:00".

Cheers Coders

Answer (score 1):

audio.duration just shows the length of the audio, not your place in the playback. The property is read-only

https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/prop_audio_duration.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function getDuration(src, destination) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    $(audio).on("loadedmetadata", function(){
        destination.textContent = audio.duration;
    });
    audio.src = src;
}
```

and then invoke getDuration as needed like this

```
var span = createOrGetSomeSpanElement();
getDuration("./audio/2.mp3", span);
```

Comment: thanks my bro, I think you might have misunderstood the question.
Right now when a song ends or next song is selected the audio.duration changes accordingly. 
I want to reset it to "00:00" if stop function is triggered. right now the current audio time resets to "00:00" but the audio.duration time remains as it was on the last song played. Needs to reset back to "00:00" (the default value of the span element).

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to reset its `src` property:

```js
const aud = document.querySelector("audio");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const log = document.querySelector("pre");

btn.onclick = function stop(evt) {
  aud.src = null;
};

setInterval(() => {
  log.textContent = aud.duration;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/transcoded/d/dc/Strawberry_Fields_Forever_(Beatles_song_-_sample).ogg/Strawberry_Fields_Forever_(Beatles_song_-_sample).ogg.mp3" controls></audio>

<button>stop</button>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: well thats one step close. 
It only works once, when the stop button is pressed, play can not be pressed again.

Comment: Yes of course, you need to choose. If you want your stop button to reset the whole <audio> tag including its `duration`, then you can't just call `play` on it and expect it to start playing again (it's just an empty audio element then). If you want to keep the ability to just call play, this means you need to keep a media loaded in it, and then it will have a `duration`. But you can very well just set the `src` again before the next `play()`, for instance somehting like `function play() { if(!aud.src) { aud.src = "file1.mp3"; } aud.play(); }`

Comment: ok, I'm starting to get it...
So right now, when pressing 'stop' button, the index stays the same, so if you are playing 2nd track and you press 'stop' then 'play' the 2nd track will play. 
So... if this line of code works (not in the code above):
 document.getElementById("songName").textContent = "Muzika Audio-Player";
(when 'stop' is pressed, the songName span changes to "Muzika Audio-Player" and then if 'play is pressed the current track title is loaded again....

Comment: ... why doesn't this line do the same?
document.getElementById("duration-time").textContent = "00:00";
It doesn't break the code but it is ignored and doesn't work

Comment: I have no idea, you are speaking about some part of the code you never shown or talked about. Aren't you the one who wrote that code? It could very well be updating this element's textContent in an interval or some other event, really can't see can't say. I can only answer the question as it's being asked, and it asks to reset the `duration` of an <audio> element, this answer does that.

Comment: yea it's a difficult one alright, sorry!
Thanks for the answers, ill keep digging!!